# How to send a Payment to Multiple Merchants using PayPal v2 JavaScript

Tags: paypal

I have an ecommerce platform that has multiple sellers selling products and I want to use PayPal checkout v2 Javascript to send a payment to multiple merchants.

Using v2 JavaScript API:
https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=CLIENT_ID&disable-funding=credit,card

```
paypal.Buttons({        
    onInit: function(data, actions)  {

    },        
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
        "purchase_units": [              
        {
          "reference_id": "1",
          "amount": {
            "currency_code": "AUD",
            "value": "20.00",
            "breakdown": {
              "item_total": {
                "currency_code": "AUD",
                "value": "20.00"
              }
            }
          },                    
          "payee": {
            "email_address": "payee1@business.example.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "reference_id": "2",
          "amount": {
            "currency_code": "AUD",
            "value": "10.00",
            "breakdown": {
              "item_total": {
                "currency_code": "AUD",
                "value": "10.00"
              }
            }
          },                    
          "payee": {
            "email_address": "payee2@business.example.com"
          }
        }
      ]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {        
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
      });
    },        
    onError: function (err)  {
      alert(err.message);
    }
}).render('#paypal-button');
```

I can login as a payer and see total $30, when I click Pay Now it says error "Order can not be captured". If I remove the second purchase unit object (payee 2) the transaction is approved.

I read on PayPal forums and api documentations and see mostly deprecated methods. How do I send a payment to multiple merchants now adays?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no mechanism for approving multiple v2/checkout/orders purchase_units with the JS checkout.
2. The deprecated methods should also not be used

> How do I send a payment to multiple merchants now adays?

You don't -- not simultaneously, anyway. Each is its own separate checkout/approval event.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create app as platform in your sandbox or live account
2. its best user experience to use js integration with multi seller checkout
3. You have pass merchantids on url and in js section as below
   if multiple seller use this

#### multiple seller

```
<script 
  src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=client_id&intent=capture&disable-funding=credit&merchant-id=*&currency=USD"  
  data-partner-attribution-id="bn_code" 
  data-merchant-id="merchant_id1,merchant_id2"
>
</script>
```

#### single seller

```
<script 
  src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=client_id&intent=capture&disable-funding=credit&merchant-id=merchant_id1&currency=USD" 
  data-partner-attribution-id="bn_code" 
  data-merchant-id="merchant_id1"
>
</script>
```

Then you have to use js sdk integration with div as below

```
paypal.Buttons({
style : {
  color: 'gold',
  shape: 'pill',
  label: 'pay',
},
createOrder: function (data, actions) {
  return actions.order.create(data.json);
},
onApprove: function (data, actions) {
  return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
    //redirect to your server
      window.location.replace(base_url+'paypal/create_order/'+details.id)
  })
},
  onCancel: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  onError: function (err) {
    // For example, redirect to a specific error page
    console.log(err);
  }
}).render('#paypal-payment-button');
```

For how to create order please check the documentation.